# Touchpad/Trackpad is not found by Ubuntu 12.10 but external USB mouse works

Tags: 12.10, kernel, xorg, mouse, trackpad

I've just attempted a reinstall of Ubuntu 12.10, which has resulted in my issue of the trackpad not working. I've run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`, but still to no avail. Here is the output of `xinput list`:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USB Optical Mouse                         id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

As you can see, X has recognised my external USB mouse but not my touchpad. How can I get it to detect the trackpad?

I'm using a Lenovo Thinkpad X220T, with Quantal 12.10 64bit, Kernel Linux 3.5.0-26-generic and GNOME 3.6.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that although I had upgraded packages, the linux kernel is in fact separate from this. By running the **Update Manager** I was able to resolve the issue by updating to `Kernel Linux 3.5.0-27-generic` and restarting.